# method returns Resource id#14 PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

New to classes.

```
public function get_feed($member_id) {



    $sql = "SELECT mc. * , cp. * 
            FROM `my_connections` mc
            LEFT JOIN `thoughts` cp ON cp.`member_id` = mc.`connection_id` 
            WHERE mc.`member_id` = '".$member_id."'
            AND mc.`approved` = 1";

    $result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

    //echo '<pre>'.$sql.'</pre>';

            return $result; //this returns Resource id#14 or NULL


    /*while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $feed_item[] = $list;
    }

    return $feed_item;*/ 

}// EO get_feed()
```

when I call it

```
$feed = new my_feed;

echo $feed->get_feed($uid);
```

it returns Null.

But when I use the same sql outside the method it returns expected result.

what should I be returning in a query like above.

Comment: $db looks like your connection string and you are using inside the function so you may need to use as global $db ; inside the function before using it.

Comment: $db? looks like a scope issue

Comment: Perhaps if you didn't suppress errors on your `mysql_query` call you would see why it's failing.

Comment: You are both correct, I missed that- Still getting the same result though when returning $result, i.e. Resource id #14

Comment: @maximl337 `mysql_query` returns a resource. That's how it is supposed to work. What are you expecting? See http://us2.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty `global` shouldn't be used in OOP. Better to use `$this->db` or similar.

Comment: @jszobody You are correct, what I want to know is, is it proper to just return $result then loop through it or to loop through it with a while loop and put the resources in an array and return that (like in the commented section of the code)

Comment: Yes if your class has the $db access or if its a part of its parent class

Comment: @maximl337 That's entirely up to you. That's a design choice.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1

Comment: And while you're at it stop using `mysql_*` and use `mysqli` or `PDO`. See http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases.

Comment: I have inherited a legacy application, I am slowly modernizing it, will make the changes soon.thank you

Comment: @jszobody anyway I can mark your answer as complete through comments. sry fairly new to SO aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. You are suppressing errors, leaving yourself in the dark:

   `$result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); // Remove the @ symbol`
2. You should then find that `$db` isn't a valid database connection object, due to scope. Make sure you have it setup as a class variable, then reference `$this->db` instead.
3. Your `Resource id#14` result is expected, that's what `mysql_query` returns. You can use the various `mysql_fetch_*` methods to parse it here, or simply return it and let the caller handle parsing.
4. Stop using `mysql_*` methods! Switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as you can (I understand that can take time with legacy applications).

Answer (score 1):

`$result` always return `Resource id#14` is the way php handle that, to get the data you have to fetch it using the functions php have for that, like [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) or
[mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $feed_item[] = $list;
}

return $feed_item;
```

`$feed _item` will have the query result into an array

**NOTE:**
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Try to avoid suppressing errors like the `@` in `@mysqli_query` you will need get the error to debug